# Using special "replace" characters in a bash script

Tags: bash, shell, scripting

I want to use the `!!`, `!$`,`^abc^cde`, etc. aliases in a bash script.
Sadly, I cant seem to make them work in a script (They work just fine in interactive mode),
Does anybody know what the problem is? If this can not be done, do you know about anything that operates in a similar way that can be used in a bash script?

Comment: What you're asking for is "history expansion". It's turned off by default in scripts, and is considered bad practice to use it in them anyhow.

Answer (score 1):

Use `set +o histexpand` to enable history expansion in non-interactive bash shells.

Comment: To be clear -- this is non-POSIX; it may work in bash scripts, but isn't guaranteed to work in any other shell.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy Well *of course* it is bash-specific.  The question has the "bash" tag, and the question mentions bash in the question and in the title.

Comment: Sure. I didn't say it was _wrong_. Keeping track of what is and isn't portable is important.

Comment: @CharlesDuffy A Bash question gets a Bash answer and does not need a POSIX non-portability disclaimer, just like a Linux programming answer does not need a Windows non-portability disclaimer.

Comment: StackOverflow answers are for a general audience, not just the person originally asking the question. Answering the initial question is relevant to scoring and acceptance, sure, but it's worth making answers comprehensive.